# Using the Hg Convert Extension, Branchmap Option

Tags: version-control, mercurial, tortoisehg

I've got 2 Mercurial repositories **RepoA** and **RepoB**, 2 people have been working independenlty on each of their repos, RepoA only has one branch(Default) but 9 commits, RepoB has 2 branches, Default and Experiment1, each of these branches have approx 30 commits. Now it turns out that RepoB is a subset of RepoA, i.e alot of the stuff in RepoB can be put into RepoA. I'd like to Pull(import) all the contents of RepoB into a branch in RepoA. I do not want the import to go the Default branch of RepoA but rather a named branch in RepoA, called **Developer1WIP**. I specifically need to know

1. How can I create a named branch(Developer1WIP) in RepoA and import ALL of RepoB into the Developer1WIP Branch on RepoA

I believe the HgConvert Extension with branch-map is a good way forward.
"The branchmap is a file that allows you to rename a branch when it is being brought in from whatever external repository."....

1. what is this file?
2. where is it to be created & what should be in it?
3. Can I get some examples of exactly how to use this command in Windows?

,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything is documented in the Mercurial wiki, here's an excerpt from the [ConvertExtension page](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension#A--branchmap):

> ...
>
> --branchmap
>
> Since v1.3
>
> The branchmap is a file that allows you to rename a branch when it is
>   being brought in from whatever external repository. When used in
>   conjunction with a splicemap, it allows for a powerful combination to
>   help fix even the most badly mismanaged repositories and turn them
>   into nicely structured Mercurial repositories. The branchmap contains
>   lines of the form
>
> ```
> original_branch_name new_branch_name
> ```
>
> "original_branch_name" is the
>   name of the branch in the source repository, and "new_branch_name" is
>   the name of the branch is the destination repository. This can be used
>   to move code in one repository from "default" to a named branch.
>
> Remember that "default" identifies the default branch of Mercurial
>   repositories, which is not displayed by default by log, heads or
>   parents commands. To erase named branch markers, convert it to
>   "default" with a branchmap like
>
> ```
> original_branch_name default
> ```
>
> The revisions will still be there but no
>   longer attached to the original named branch.
>
> ...

So basically you'll create a textfile containing this:

```
default Developer1WIP
Experiment1 Developer1WIP
```

*(do you want both default and Experiment1 on the same branch after conversion? your question was a bit unclear but I assumed you did.)*

Then issue the convert command:

```
hg convert ORIGINAL_REPO CONVERTED_REPO --branchmap MAP.TXT
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I did read the documentation but wasn't clear on what went where. Your example was clear enough. Many thanks