# Importing unrelated repo into another repo in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I have two Mercurial repositories. Both repos have their own unrelated history. Let's call them:

- "Main" (contains the project itself)
- "Lab" (contains some related content)

I would now like to "import" the `Lab` repo into the `Main` repo with the following constraints:

- Both repos shall keep their history.
- `Lab` shall be stored as a subfolder in `Main`.
- The changes from `Lab` shall be be located in a branch which gets merged into `Main`.

Following https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MergingUnrelatedRepositories basically works but doesn't create a branch.

Comment: *doesn't create a branch* depends on what you mean by "branch". If you want the branch named `default` in the incoming repository to get *renamed* to some other name (so that the imported commits don't share the branch name), you might use the Convert extension. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7567636/using-the-hg-convert-extension-branchmap-option

Comment: Related: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/101243/64 (in Portuguese, but the pictures can help)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a repository `Main` and `Lab`, you can merge the `Lab` repository into the Main repository and rename its default branch to some other name by doing the following with the `convert` extension:

1. Create a file "branchmap.txt" containing `default Lab`.  Using this branchmap, the Lab changesets in the "default" branch will be named "Lab".  If you have other branches in your Lab repository, you may want additional entries.
2. Run `hg convert Lab Main --branchmap branchmap.txt`.  This assumes the Lab and Main repository directories, and the branchmap.txt file, are in the current directory.  Adjust paths accordingly.  The Lab changesets will be added to the Main repository.
3. In the Main repository, the following commands will move the Lab files into a Lab subdirectory then merge the Lab branch with default.
   a. `hg update Lab`
   b. `mkdir Lab`
   c. `hg move * Lab`
   d. `hg ci -m "Moved Lab files to Lab subdirectory"`
   e. `hg update default`
   f. `hg merge Lab`
   g. `hg ci -m Merge`

Now you can continue to modify the Lab branch in the future and merge to default as needed.

Comment: You could also do this with "hg pull --force" to pull the unrelated repo and then merge the two heads you'll end up with together. In this case you'd end up with a repo with two root changesets, which may be confusing, but this way you get to preserve the changeset hashes for one of the repos.

Comment: @ngoldbaum Yes, but that doesn't rename the incoming repo to a new branch, and for the merge the renaming of the files into a subdirectory still needs to be done.  You get two root changesets with this method as well, but `hg convert` also renames the incoming default branch to another name.